# Increase Reputation Requirements for Tag Creation

Tags: discussion, feature-request

OP in [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/6740/what-is-the-difference-between-a-start-up-and-a-small-company-which-is-not-a-sta), a new user, just created a new tag, "company" - which I believe is a bad tag for many reasons.

Now that we are putting so much effort into cleaning up the tags, and that we have established a tag base, can we increase reputation requirements for creating tags, such that these don't go by without involving at least one senior user? And, by that, I mean say 150-200 rep. Not a lot, but just to prevent first-questions-tags.

Comment: Conversation revealed that he created the tag "by accident".

Comment: I will check into this. As far as I know, the policy is set at a network level, with the bar for tag creation being deliberately low for sites in beta.

Answer (score 1):

The reputation required for creating tags is low at [125 reputation points](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) because a tag could always be edited with a few simple clicks.

Raising the barrier would not help so much because those who create wrong tags will continue to do so without trying to learn how they work. Believe me I saw over 1,000 rep users creating wrong tags on other SE sites.

Therefore, the best thing to do is just remove the tag and place a proper tag so that [it will be destroyed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213993/what-scripts-run-at-300-utc) (a tag without any question under it is destroyed automatically).

No matter where the barrier is, those who want to learn will learn and those who don't will keep creating mess that needs your editing or clean-up. Posting a comment to a new user who created a new irrelevant tag will definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

There are still a lot of tags that can be added to the pool. Most of the top users it seems are those who know a lot about many topics, as opposed to those who specialize in one field, who might want a new tag. Simple topics like "human capital" haven't popped up as tags yet as well, and we might as well have too many tags than too few, in my opinion. We can always clean up tags anyhow.

That said, I don't know how many new tags people like to make and whether it is badly abused. As more people come in though, we'll naturally get more odd tags--and the market demand for mods should rise accordingly :P

Comment: I disagree with the first premise - top users don't necessarily know al to about many topics - I don't - but they are more active. However, that point is futile, I don't want to require 1000 reputation for tags. I was rather thinking about 150, just barely enough to stop people from adding new tags with their *first* two questions. If they are repeating customers, they'll get the hang of things.

Comment: I guess that wouldn't be too bad. But then a lot of privileges are going to be clustered around the 100-200 range it feels like. Maybe that actually would be good for getting people to keep on doing the econ stackexchange lifestyle.